# comparing data frames from multiple data frames to filter data and extract relevant features

Tags: python, pandas

I try to load my all data-set files in python using pandas but the results are not shown.

```
import os
print(os.listdir("C:/Users/Smile/.spyder-py3/datasets"))
# Any results you write to the current directory are saved as output.
data = ["name","version","tool_name","wmc","dit","noc","cbo","rfc","lcom","ca","ce","npm","lcom3","loc","dam","moa","mfa","cam","ic","cbm","amc","max_cc","avg_cc","bug"]
data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        data = pd.read_csv(file)
        data.set_index('name',inplace = True)
        data = data.append(data, ignore_index=True
                           )
print(data.head(5))


    ************************************************************************

My output is given below:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: Your `data` variable is assigned multiple times with different content. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

you overwrite data each time you read a new CSV

replace the **data** variable with a temp variable, like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        csv_data = pd.read_csv(file)
        csv_data.set_index('name',inplace = True)
        data = data.append(csv_data, ignore_index=True)

print(data.head(5))
```

by using data to read a new csv data each time 'data = pd.read_csv(file)', you overwrite the data you already appended in the last iteration, you need to keep it intact in order to keep appending to it, so each CSV read must be separated.

Comment: Thank you for guideline. I checked your code I get indent error. Please remove this error I couldn't remove it.

Comment: hello, I fixed it, but you really didnt need to copy paste my code, if you understood what I wrote you would know what to do (simply change the name 'data' inside the for loop where you assign the csv content), therefore, If you have questions about my solution, let me know and i'll explain. anyway, i recommend that you wont copy and paste codes, try to fully understand the solution to the level where you can code it yourself.